# RequestBuilder and RequestCallback performance issue

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT RequestBuilder and I see request call back takes very long time to be handled although the time required for request handling in server side is good, below is my code, is there away to prioritize request call back so it will be handled quickly

```
        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URLs.getHpEquipmentIndigoDetails(equipmentId));
        float timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if (SmartPlannerConstants.SUCCESS_STATUS == response.getStatusCode()) {
                final float currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.debug("Time consumed on send & recieve request " + (currentTime-timeStart));
                // Initialize widget and update UI 
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                SmartPlannerWindowManager.showError(exception);
            }
        });
            final float timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.debug("Time consumed on send request " + (timeEnd-timeStart));



        Result:
        Time consumed on send request zero ms
        Firebug says request handling on server is 200 ms
        Time consumed on send & recieve request is 4000 ms
```

Comment: Time consumed on send request is zero because the request is async. Do you have any log server side to confirm the time required on elaborating the request?

Comment: Can you try a similar request with other server, for example a simple request on google home page?

Comment: Thanks for your corporation, I'm not confused why the time consumed on send request is zero ms, my only concerns why there is a huge difference between the time given by firebug which is (200ms) and time printed on my logs statement (4000ms), the difference is huge (4000/200) = 20 times !!

Comment: Are you getting the same results from firebug in production? Have you tried with Chrome dev tools?

Comment: I got this in production, the same in chrome dev tools also!